# android touch feedback

Tags: android, android-styles

Styling for the application I noticed that some elements had `touch feedback` while others did not ...

Rather than giving a custom color for the touch feedback which would not be good for a uniform feel in the app, how can I invoke the default color for touch feedback on any given device ??

Like for `API 10 and lower` its **orange**, `11 and up` its **blue** and from `KitKat` its `white`. Is there a way to do this or is it just not possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's

```
android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default_normal"
```